# Parameter disappear in PlayMode (Unity)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm a noob at this.
There is a problem that I could not solve alone, and I want you to help me, it turns out that every time I enter the unity playmode, the parameters of a script disappear. I don't know if it's because of my script or it's something else. Anyway I leave you screenshots of my project in unity and the problematic script. Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I press the "Atacar" button, I get the error below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in `Start()` you are trying to get the component GameObject, which does not exist. You already have the GameObject references and GameObjects do not have components GameObjects. A Component is a piece of a GameObject but a GameObject can not have GameObject Component.

If you remove your current `Start()` function the object should not disappear when you hit Play.

You only need to use the GetComponent method when you are trying to get a Component on an object you have a reference to. For instance, if you wanted to get a reference to the `Sprite Render` on your gameobject and did not want to make a public variable, you can get that reference by using `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>()`.

If you are still confused about the overall concept of the Component to GameObject relationship, you can check out the [official docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/520/Documentation/Manual/TheGameObject-ComponentRelationship.html) or [another useful Unity post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/42472/whats-the-difference-between-the-component-and-gam.html#:%7E:text=3%20Replies&text=GameObjects%20are%20all%20the%20same,contain%20(instances%20of)%20components.).